# What is different between u-boot.bin and u-boot.img

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I just compiled the U-Boot bootloader and I see a few file names in the u-boot program directory which are:

```
u-boot.bin
u-boot.img
u-boot.lds
u-boot.srec
```

Basically, I'm interested in the files with extensions `.img` and `.bin`. What is different between them?
Is `u-boot.img` for SD card and `u-boot.bin` for flashing to NAND ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`u-boot.bin` is the binary compiled U-Boot bootloader.

`u-boot.img` contains `u-boot.bin` along with an additional header to be used by the boot ROM to determine how and where to load and execute U-Boot.

The way in which these files are deployed can depend upon the nature of your device, its boot ROM and where the files are loaded from.

Boot ROMs are generally provided by the SoC/CPU vendor.  These days, many boot ROMs are capable of loading `u-boot.img`, reading the file's header, loading `u-boot.bin` into memory and finally executing it.  Some boot ROMs are complex enough to load `u-boot.bin` directly or even the OS kernel.  While others may load an intermediate bootloader (MLO/X-Loader) first which then takes responsibility for loading U-Boot as the secondary bootloader once external memory is initialized.

This image depicts the latter case as implemented by some TI OMAP processors:
[image: TI OMAP Boot Sequence]

This boot process is reduced by some devices by moving many of the X-Loader tasks into U-Boot and placing boot parameters (such as memory addresses) into the header of `u-boot.img` avoiding the need for an intermediate bootloader.

You will need to investigate the properties of your device to determine how you should go about deploying U-Boot.

Comment: I'm Lost. So what is role MLO ? Whether is u-boot.bin + MLO =  u-boot.img ? So for what single u-boot.bin. When I should be use u-boot.bin and when I should be used u-boot.img ?

Comment: Super ! Now I see this conception. In my device using u-boot-img. It's read all data form SD card. My device is TI Sitara am335x. In worked kit each I recived from vendor is on card find file MLO + u-boot.img+uEnv.txt+uImage. What is content of headers in u-boot.img ?

Comment: I stiil see as You added new information which are very helpful and professjonal. Thank You. So, it remains my analysis of the documentation this MPU, and learn, learn, learn.